# MongoDB 400's after live deploy

Tags: node.js, mongodb, heroku

I apologize that this is probably a fairly vague question/issue. I just got my project hosted live and noticed that all of my requests to the database are returning with a 400. I'm using Axios to make the calls to MongoDB. I'm hosting my website through Heroku. I got the hobby tier for an SSL cert and activated it. The domain name is through GoDaddy and I have the forwarding address set to https://.... My cluster is a shared-tier cluster. I've searched around for similar issues, but only found docs related to a replica set. Is this required to go live or something? I've triple checked that my connection string in heroku is accurate. I'm at a loss. I've hosted a few smaller projects with the same node, mongo, heroku, ect before and it worked fine. The only difference with this project is the SSL and the custom domain.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think this is happening because I need to whitelist the IP address. I allowed all access and it was working. I do no want to keep that setting active though since it feels less secure. What IP address do I need to add exactly? I went to the website site24x7 and checked there but it came back with 8 different results. They had an IP at the end of each string, so I added those. Didn't work. I went to GoDaddy and added the "A" field and that did not work either. 

How do I know what IP I should be using here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I must have had a long day. I didn't have the whitelist IP setup...